# Overriding default Html for ASP.NET controls

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5.

I've noticed some rubbishness in terms of the output for the ASP.NET controls. For instance the asp:checkbox renders nonsense if it is disabled which is a problem for XHTML compliance.

Is there a way to override a method etc to control the Xhtml the controls give you.

Comment: As a side note for others who read this, ASP.NET MVC gives you the ability to fully control your output to the browser. This isn't an answer to this question but just a bit of extra useful information for those stumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that using [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use control adapters to change how the control renders itself. For example, a lot of people like to use CSS layouts and since ASP.NET controls render out tables, there's [CSS friendly adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/) which you can use instead.